# How can I get datediff with groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dateframe 'df' which stores users' orders:

```
    user_id order_date
0         a 2018-01-17
1         a 2018-04-29
2         a 2018-05-19
3         a 2018-05-21
4         a 2018-06-15
5         b 2018-09-18
6         b 2019-01-30
7         b 2019-02-01
8         b 2019-07-03
9         c 2019-07-31
10        c 2019-12-10
11        c 2019-12-12
12        c 2019-12-24
```

The 'order_date' is already ordered. I want to know the date diff of different users of different orders. I need to use 'groupby' to seperate the users and then calculate the datediff. The result should be:

```
    user_id   datediff
0         a         NA
1         a        102
2         a         20
3         a          2
4         a         25
5         b         NA
6         b        134
7         b          2
8         b        152
9         c         NA
10        c        132
11        c          2
12        c         12
```

I know how to get this by using a naive loop. How to get it in a better way like shift or rolling?Btw, you dont have to get an exactly the same result. The 'NA' could be 'NAT'. The '102' could be '102 days'.

Further more, how can I get the means of datediff of different users? The result should be:

```
    user_id   mean_datediff
0         a           37.25
1         b           68.00   
2         c           48.67
```

For user a, the mean value is (102+20+2+25)/4=37.25, not 149/5.

And the last step is add the 'mean_datediff' to the original df. The expected output is:

```
    user_id order_date mean_datediff
0         a 2018-01-17         37.25
1         a 2018-04-29         37.25
2         a 2018-05-19         37.25
3         a 2018-05-21         37.25
4         a 2018-06-15         37.25
5         b 2018-09-18         68.00
6         b 2019-01-30         68.00
7         b 2019-02-01         68.00
8         b 2019-07-03         68.00
9         c 2019-07-31         48.67
10        c 2019-12-10         48.67
11        c 2019-12-12         48.67
12        c 2019-12-24         48.67
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for difference, [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) for convert timedeltas to days:

```
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])

df['datediff'] = df.groupby(['user_id'])['order_date'].diff().dt.days
print (df)
   user_id order_date  datediff
0        a 2018-01-17       NaN
1        a 2018-04-29     102.0
2        a 2018-05-19      20.0
3        a 2018-05-21       2.0
4        a 2018-06-15      25.0
5        b 2018-09-18       NaN
6        b 2019-01-30     134.0
7        b 2019-02-01       2.0
8        b 2019-07-03     152.0
9        c 2019-07-31       NaN
10       c 2019-12-10     132.0
11       c 2019-12-12       2.0
12       c 2019-12-24      12.0
```

And if necessary integers add [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) with `Int64`, [working pandas 0.24+](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])

df['datediff'] = df.groupby(['user_id'])['order_date'].diff().dt.days.astype('Int64')
print (df)
   user_id order_date  datediff
0        a 2018-01-17       NaN
1        a 2018-04-29       102
2        a 2018-05-19        20
3        a 2018-05-21         2
4        a 2018-06-15        25
5        b 2018-09-18       NaN
6        b 2019-01-30       134
7        b 2019-02-01         2
8        b 2019-07-03       152
9        c 2019-07-31       NaN
10       c 2019-12-10       132
11       c 2019-12-12         2
12       c 2019-12-24        12
```

EDIT:

For new column filled by `mean`s use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function:

```
df['mean_datediff'] = (df.groupby(['user_id'])['order_date']
                         .transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.mean()))
print (df)
   user_id order_date  mean_datediff
0        a 2018-01-17      37.250000
1        a 2018-04-29      37.250000
2        a 2018-05-19      37.250000
3        a 2018-05-21      37.250000
4        a 2018-06-15      37.250000
5        b 2018-09-18      96.000000
6        b 2019-01-30      96.000000
7        b 2019-02-01      96.000000
8        b 2019-07-03      96.000000
9        c 2019-07-31      48.666667
10       c 2019-12-10      48.666667
11       c 2019-12-12      48.666667
12       c 2019-12-24      48.666667
```

Comment: Incredible. Thanks for your sharing!

Comment: What if I want to know the means of datediff of different users? Can you help me solve this problem further?

Comment: @xiaoluohao - Can you edit question for expected output?

Comment: @xiaoluohao - Answer was edited, added last paragraph output.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!